Ag-grid table that fits the contents for many columns, but also fit width for few columns
I have an ag-grid (in javascript) that sometimes can have many columns, and others just a few (and they have different contets/sizes). I'd like to have an auto-size that fits at least the content (so, the columns can occupy a larger width than the grid size, with horizontal scrolling), but if there are only few columns, they'd stretch to fill the whole grid. The autoSizeStrategy type: 'fitCellContents' fit the contents, but when I have few columns, it does not occupy the whole grid. On the other hand, type: 'fitGridWidth' sometimes make the cells smaller than the contents. Is there a way to achieve both?
PS: I have flex: 1, in the defaultColDef and I'm using the CSS (mainly due to some alignments issues and to display ellipsis for large contents):
.ag-cell {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 2px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ag-cell-wrapper {
  text-align: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

I guess this may affect the behaviour I'm trying to achieve.
edit: I have removed all autoSizeStrategy and all the calls to auto-size the columns. It seems that using minWidth in some columns is breaking the flex:1 behaviour, even though the documentation says The flex config does not work with a width config in the same column. If you need to provide a minimum width for a column, you should use flex and the minWidth config. Flex will also take maxWidth into account.:

When I remove all minWidth from the column definitions, all cells extend to fit the grid.
edit2: Same thing when I add flex: 2 in a given column, they stop stretching and look like the screenshot above.
